# Laravel image upload on webhosting

Tags: php, laravel

The problem is that my image upload is working on localhost, but as soon as I upload it on my webhosting it doesn't.

What I think the problem is, is that my project on webhosting is like "root" -> Project (all Laravel folders except public)/public_html (obviously public folder from Laravel project), and on localhost are standard Laravel folders.

So, I think somehow, because of the different folder hierarchy, the controller mistakes the image folder route and the upload fails.

Controller code:

```
public function unos(Request $request){
    $request->validate([
       'inputUsername' => ['required'],
        'inputPassword' => ['required'],
        'ddlUloga' => ['required'],
        'ddlDrzava' => ['required'],
        'inputSlika' => ['required'],
    ], [
        'required' => 'Polje :attribute je obavezno!'
    ]);

    $kor = new Korisnik();
    $kor->username = $request->get("inputUsername");
    $kor->password = $request->get("inputPassword");
    $kor->uloga_id = $request->get("ddlUloga");
    $kor->drzava_id = $request->get("ddlDrzava");
    $slika = $request->file("inputSlika");

    $tmp_putanja = $slika->getPathName(); // tmp putanja
    $ekstenzija = $slika->getClientOriginalExtension(); // vraca: jpg, png - bez .
    $ime_fajla = time().'.'.$ekstenzija;
    $putanja = 'images/profilne/'.$ime_fajla;
    $kor->slika_url = $putanja;
    $putanja_server = public_path($putanja);

    try {
        File::move($tmp_putanja, $putanja_server);

        $rez = $kor->insertKorisnika();

        if($rez == 1){  
            return redirect()->back()->with("message", "Uspešno uneto");
        }
        else {
            return redirect()->back()->with("greska", "Greška pri unosu");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $ex){
        \Log::error('MOJA GRESKA: '.$ex->getMessage());
    }
}
```

I'm unable to solve this problem and I'd be gratefull for any help.

Comment: Show us how your controller handles uploads. I'd bet on a permissions issue to the `storage` directory, but it's hard to say without the code.

Comment: edited the main post

Comment: OK. So, as a general rule, you don't want to be putting stuff directly in the `public` folder, as setting permissive permissions there is going to make it your install less secure - *especially* on shared hosting. Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#file-uploads - it's as simple as `$path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');` to store an upload. No need for all the `getPathName`, `getClientOriginalExtension`, `File::move` stuff at all.

Comment: @ceejayoz , the thing is, i remembered the laravel.log file and saw the error about the file upload and its as i have thought

Comment: [2018-05-02 22:30:51] local.ERROR: MOJA GRESKA: rename(/storage/ssd3/462/217462/tmp/phpa9CHjz,/storage/ssd3/462/217462/projekat/public/images/profilne/1525300251.jpg): No such file or directory